# Python: insert into list faster than O(N)?

Tags: python, list, insert

I have a sorted list L and I have a binary search for determining where in the list to insert an element such that the resulting list will still be in order.

However L.insert(index,object) needs O(N) time complexity.

Is there another data structure for L that will serve the same purpose, but allows for a faster insertion?

Comment: Binary search tree? Looks like Python doesn't have one built in, but there's probably a package somewhere for one.

Comment: Yeah Binary Search Tree is O(1) insertion.

Comment: Ahh I was hoping you guys weren't going to say BST. :(

Comment: @JamesMills Don't you mean O(log n)?

Comment: It's practically impossible O(1) in a BST. In a BST is O(log n) on average, and O(n) worst case.

Comment: What do you actually need this for?

Comment: Apparently `bintrees` has both unbalanced and balanced trees. So the Red-Black or AVL trees from that give you `O(log n)` worse case for the operations you mention. You lose `O(1)` access by index, but it's still `O(n)` overall for an iteration.

Comment: Take a look at the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) library, `bisect.insort()`

Comment: @HaiVu From the documentation of `bisect.insort()`: "Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow **O(n)** insertion step."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the blist module.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/

It claims O(log n) insertion.

usage:

```
x = #list contents
y = blist(x)
y.insert(index, object) #now works in O(log n)
```

Comment: This library is also very efficient for inserting/deleting at random locations in _unsorted_ lists (where the order matters).

Answer (score 5):

A shout out to [`sortedcontainers.SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/). This will keep your list in order automatically, with a fast insert time.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

mylist = SortedList([1, 2, 4, 5])
mylist.add(3)
mylist
#>>> SortedList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], load=1000)
```

`SortedList` [insertions are amortized `O(sqrt n)`, or `O(cbrt n)` with different choices of parameters,](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-scale.html) but it scales better than `blist`, which is `O(log n)`, because the constants are much better. There is [a very in-depth look at performance on their website](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-workload.html).

Alternatively, you might be wanting a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) in which case you can get potentially-faster inserts with [the `heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).

Comment: The `O(log n)` part is [not strictly true](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-scale.html). `sortedcontainers.SortedList` stores data in [balanced lists of lists](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html) and exploits data locality achieving faster amortized times. Big-O insert complexity is, strictly speaking, `O(n^2)`, but due to large "load factor", amortized insert complexity is ~ `n^(1/3)`.

Comment: @randomir Thanks, this is actually something [I was aware of](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4ge9xs/python_sorted_collections/d2hkra5/), just not at the time I wrote this. My post is fixed now.

Comment: Still a good answer, though (I wasn't aware of `sortedcontainers`, probably because I didn't need them until today :)).